# Non significant nuisance factor and interaction

Tags: anova, interaction, blocking

[image: My problem]

I had this problem,it simply to see that the variable "Day" can be viewed as nuisance factor. This is my anova table:

```
  Factor coding (-1; 0; +1)
        Factor Information
        Factor Type Levels Values
        Temperature Fixed 3 -1; 0; 1
        Time Fixed 3 -1; 0; 1
        Day Fixed 2 1; 2
        
        Analysis of Variance
        
        Source         DF Adj SS Adj MS F-Value P-Value
           Temperature 2 1985,33 992,67  8,39    0,011
           Time        2 2908,33 1454,17 12,28   0,004
           Day         1 40,50   40,50   0,34    0,575
      Temperature*Time 4 459,33  114,83  0,97    0,474
       
        S       R-sq   R-sq(adj) R-sq(pred)
        10,8800 85,06% 68,26%    24,39%`
```

a) The nuisance factor, that is not significative , can be removed?
b) is right make the first analysis without interaction (Time*Temperature) to see that the nuisance factor is not significative and , after, add the interaction on the second model (without nuisance factor) and analyze it?

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE!  Please take a moment to review our [tour].  Also, if this is a `self-study` question, please tag it accordingly.

Comment: This is homework or an exam problem and as Tavrock says it definitely needs a self study tag.